# After answering questions and also being accepted require to help if questioner gets in some other problem?

Tags: discussion

We should help them if they get in other problem? Like i answered the question in accordance to question which was asked. My answer was also accepted. Now, after some time e.g. hour, day or two. The questioner say that i am now in this issue. Should we help them or they need to add other question for it?

Comment: Answer if you want to. Don't if you don't. In general, though, it's helpful to separate different questions into different posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in no obligation to listen to them. Politely decline, or don't respond at all. Or tell them to post a new question. Of course, you *can* help if you want to :)

See also: [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)